# OpenCV 3.1.0 with Python 3.5

Tags: python, linux, opencv, python-3.5, opencv3.1

After following several different tutorials, guides and steps recommended in other SO answers I didn't manage to install OpenCV for use with Python 3.5 in my Ubuntu 16.04 system.

As long as OpenCV 3.1.0 officially supports Python 3.x, how do I install it appropriately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed installing Python 3.5 and OpenCV library appropriately in my system after gathering steps and troubleshooting solutions over different tutorials and guides.

*The installation is performed under a virtualenv, so there is no need to clean up previous install attempts footprints from your system.*

Following the steps presented here you'll install:

- openCV 3.1.0
- opencv_contrib 3.1.0
- numpy
- scipy
- scikit
- matplotlib
- cython
- venv

At the end, **it may take up to 20Gb of space** if you haven't already installed any of those packages previously.

*You will need gcc-4.9+ for compiling OpenCV, I tested it with gcc-5.4*

## Install OpenCV dependencies

```
sudo apt-get build-dep -y opencv
```

## Create and setup a virtualenv

```
sudo apt-get install python3-venv
python3.5 -m venv python35-opencv31
source ~/python35-opencv31/bin/activate
pip install matplotlib
pip install numpy
pip install scipy
pip install scikit-learn
pip install cython
pip install -U scikit-image
```

## Compile OpenCV 3.1.0 and openvc_contrib 3.1.0

### Dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libjasper-dev libdc1394-22-dev
```

### Getting repositories

```
mkdir ~/git
cd ~/git
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
cd ./opencv
git checkout 3.1.0

cd ~/git
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib.git
cd ./opencv_contrib
git checkout 3.1.0
```

### Making sure some libs will be found

**ffmpeg libs**

```
sudo -i
mkdir /usr/include/ffmpeg
cd /usr/include/ffmpeg
ln -sf /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec/*.h ./
ln -sf /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat/*.h ./
ln -sf /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswscale/*.h ./
```

If, during compilation, occurs any problems when trying to find some ffmpeg libs, uninstall ffmpeg and [build it from source](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

**python bindings with opencv_contrib modules**

```
echo "\nfind_package(HDF5)\ninclude_directories(\${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS})" >> ~/git/opencv/modules/python/common.cmake
```

### Compiling

```
source ~/python35-opencv31/bin/activate
mkdir ~/opencv3.1.0
cd ~/git/opencv/
mkdir release
cd ./release
export CC=$(which gcc)
export CXX=$(which g++)
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/opencv3.1.0 \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/git/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-D_FORCE_INLINES" ..
```

The output should include this:

```
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /home/rodrigo/anaconda/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.12)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.12)
--     numpy:                       /home/rodrigo/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.10.4)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/site-packages
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /home/rodrigo/python35-opencv/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.2)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so (ver 3.5.2)
--     numpy:                       /home/rodrigo/python35-opencv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.2)
--     packages path:               lib/python3.5/site-packages
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /home/rodrigo/anaconda/bin/python2.7
```

Now:

```
make
```

If it succeed, then:

```
make install
```

## Add OpenCV libs to your virtualenv

```
cd ~/python35-opencv31/lib/site-packages
ln -s ~/opencv3.1.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

## Done!

To test if it works as expected:

```
cd ~
source ~/python35-opencv31/bin/activate
python
import cv2
cv2.__version__
```

It should import cv2 and show version number 3.1.0.

Comment: I found all the possible CFLAGS to be a bit cumbersome when I installed OpenCV. I'd definitely recommend something like `cmake-gui` for assistance. `sudo apt-get install cmake-qt-gui`